# Javascript Arrays do not have functionality within Angular service when retrieved from $cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, service, typeerror

The code below works fine in a controller.

```
$cookies.pinnedVidsCookie = [];
var array = $cookies.pinnedVidsCookie;
array.push({ "title": "sometitle", "embed": "somehtml" });
$cookies.pinnedVidsCookie = array;
```

However, when I put this into a service, I get an error indicating that push( ) is not an undefined function. "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

I checked and array is an object at that point of execution so its not undefined/null.

I have 'ngCookies' included in a module that includes 'pinServices' module.

```
angular.module('pinServices', [])
    .service('pinVidModal', ['$cookies', function ($cookies) {
        $cookies.pinnedVidsCookie = [];

        var pinVid = function (title, embedHtml) {
            //pinnedVids.push({ "title": title, "embed": embedHtml });
            var array = $cookies.pinnedVidsCookie;
            array.push({ "title": title, "embed": embedHtml });
            $cookies.pinnedVidsCookie = array;
        }
 return {
            pinVid: pinVid,
        };
    }]);
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

Try to console log typedef of $cookies.pinnedVidsCookie and array variable.
If these are not of array types then you have to convert them first into array, only then push method can be applied.
Else you can use $extend method to merge your object with other object.